# Get variables from executed or from not the same void

Tags: java

I'm making an aplication and I need to get the value of a variable located in one method from other without return the value

that's the code I have:

```
public void first(){
    if (var1 == 2){
        System.out.println(var1);
    }
}
public void second(){
    int var1=2;
}
```

The output will be empty.
So how can I get the varable's(var1's) value from the other void?

Comment: ... could you try to explain it better?

Answer (score 4):

In Java local variables are not accessible outside of its scope. If you want a variable to be used in both methods, then you need to declare `var1` as your class field.

For instance:

```
class MyClass {

    private int var1;

    public void first(){
        if (var1 == 2){
            System.out.println(var1);
        }
    }

    public void second(){
        var1=2;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int var1
```

is a local variable of `second()` method. You can use this variable only inside `second()` method. You can not use any local variable of any method in another method. You can create `int var1` as class instance variable.